# Receiving "Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" in multithreaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, enumerator

Presently, I am writing an application that periodically drains a singleton collection:

```
            lock (_lockItemsReceivedObject)
            {
                DateTime commitTime = DateTime.Now;
                while (ItemsReceivedInstance.Count > 0)
                {
                    ProcessInfo(commitTime);
                }
            }
```

Here is ProcessInfo:

```
   private void ProcessInfo(DateTime commitTime)
    {
        Dictionary<Int32, Item>.Enumerator enumerator = 
            ItemsReceivedInstance.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Item item = enumerator.Current.Value;
            // put item into persistent storage and perform other processing...
            ItemsReceivedInstance.Remove(enumerator.Current.Key);
        }
    }
```

Here are more details on the exception:

```
Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. at  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Elsewhere in the program other threads are receiving items and putting them into the singleton ItemsReceivedInstance collection.  What doesn't make sense to me, however, is that since I am using a lock, the ItemsReceivedInstance collection should not be able to be modified until it is emptied as the process exits the critical section, so why am I receiving this exception?  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you, CodeWeed and Wayne, for your comments.  Would this be an acceptable way to modify the collection?

```
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<Int32, Item>.Enumerator enumerator = 
            ItemsReceivedInstance.GetEnumerator();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Item item = enumerator.Current.Value;
            // put item into persistent storage and perform other processing...
            var itemToRemove = enumerator.Current.Key;
            enumerator.Dispose();
            ItemsReceivedInstance.Remove(itemToRemove);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Thank you CodeWeed and Wayne, and everyone else who considered this issue.  The foreach loop enumerator allows dirty reads, so to take a snapshot of the dictionary I am using ToArray() (see http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx), so this is how I have modified the code:

```
DateTime commitTime = DateTime.Now; 

foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32, Item> kvp in ItemsReceivedInstance.ToArray())
{
    ProcessInfo(commitTime, kvp.Value);
}

...

private static void ProcessInfo(DateTime commitTime, Item item)
{
    // put item into persistent storage and perform other processing...
}
```

Comment: You are removing from the 'ItemsReceivedInstance'. Once you remove something from it, the subsequent while loop check "ItemsReceivedInstacne.Count" will throw, because the of the underlying collection has been changed.

Comment: OK, I know I cannot modify a collection if I am using a foreach loop, but this also applies if I use an enumerator at all?

Comment: It's specifically the enumerator that stipulates that the collection enumerated can't change while you're enumerating it.

Comment: foreach is just a syntatic sugar on top of the enumeration pattern.

Comment: you are trying to access a "enumerator" that has been disposed in the last statement...  "enumerator.Current.Key" You will get an exception again saying ObjectDisposedException. There will be more trouble. I think you should think about the problem, I am sure there is a cleaner solution what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have a look at the concurrent collections.

Comment: Technically that may work, but I think it's still way too contrived. Why not pass a KeyValuePair<> into your ProcessInfo method and then call ProcessInfo inside a foreach (var kvp in ItemsReceived) ..., then Clear() the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically that may work, but I think it's still way too contrived. Why not:

```
    DateTime commitTime = DateTime.Now; 
    foreach (var kvp in ItemsReceivedInstance)
    {
        ProcessInfo(commitTime, kvp);
    }
    ItemsReceivedInstance.Clear();

    ...

    private static void ProcessInfo(DateTime commitTime, KeyValuePair<int, Item> kvp)
    {
        // put item into persistent storage and perform other processing...
    }
```

Note that a subtle difference between this and what you were trying to achieve originally is on the imapct of exceptions in `ProcessInfo`. If you're handling an exception and don't potentially want to re-process an item in your dictionary as a result, you'll want to track which items are successfully processed and remove those from the dictionary, perhaps in a `finally` block.